# Google Finance API address has changed

Tags: finance, quantitative-finance, google-finance

Until yesterday the following URL (Google Finance API)

> https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=TSLA&x=NASDAQ&i=3600&p=5d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v

would lead to a nice comma delimited data table with TSLA stock data. Since yesterday, the same call gets redirected to the standars google finance website for TSLA https://www.google.com/search?q=TSLA&tbm=fin. Does someone maybe know the new API address or has any information on the Google Finance API status? Changing the URL to

> https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?q=TSLA&x=NASDAQ&i=3600&p=5d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v

does not help, as it also redirects to the normal website.

Comment: Little off topic but, can someone recommend potential alternatives to Google Finance API?

Comment: Try Yahoo Finance api. It still works.